# Presenting floorplan data accessibly

Tags: accessibility, image

On a website there is a page which gives details about building including hire data, contact info and other things that can be marked up semantically and accessibly.

On the same page there is a large image which presents a detailed floor plan of the building, including measurements, facilities and a key to denote the various uses of the rooms.

Normally an image that conveys extra meaning to the user can be made more accessible by the inclusion of an alt tag that which would be used to convey that meaning using basic text that could be understood by screen readers etc. however, in the case of a floorplan the data is far too complex to be conveyed like this.

What would be the best way to convey the meaning in a floorplan to a user who was not able to consume visual content?

Comment: Related: [Which alternative text (alt) for static maps?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/31729/17023)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be considering a generally helpful set of information that might cover a variety of accessibility scenarios, not just visual impairment

You obviously can't meaningfully describe a complete floorplan in words, nor do you need to even try.

What is important is to give enough information for someone to quickly determine whether the building is a possible shortlist candidate to be investigated further, or if it can be rejected immediately.

So for example, information that might help in this situation could include:

- A separate list of main and notable features
- Pertinent overview statistics
- Barriers or notable advantages to physical accessibility
- A reference and a contact name, email and phone number for more information

The latter being the fallback case that allows specific questions to be answered in the likely event that you haven't supplied *everything* the user needs to know.

And... do it in a way that not only serves to fulfill your users' accessibility needs but also becomes a useful set of information for *all* users!